# Is it possible to privatize marriage while keeping incestuous relationships illegal?

Tags: libertarianism, marriage

The concept of [marriage privatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_privatization), where the state has no authority to define personal relationships, has been growing popular over the last few years in the USA. Many people see it as the best solution to the gay marriage issue and a possible compromise between both sides.

However, there have been some concerns expressed by certain groups, particularly by religious conservatives over this concept as it would result possibly in the legalization of polygamous and incestuous relationships.

My question is whether it is possible to keep incestuous relationships illegal while at the same time, keeping the government out of marriage? Have any libertarian think-tanks addressed this issue?

Comment: If your marriage is juste a private oath  what real value does it have ?

Comment: incestuous or polygamous relationships are not illegal. The government just does not recognise those relationships as marriages. If marital status had no legal recognition, how can you say any marriage is legal *or* illegal?

Comment: By illegal, I meant not recognised. @Caleth.

Comment: *has been growing popular* seems a bit of a stretch, innit?  *Has been talked about* seems more realistic.

Comment: It's not just a private oath. Its based purely on a legal contract made between two or more individuals. The difference is that the state will not be involved in the contract making process. It'll require registration. @Bougainville

Comment: Under that definition, the proposal is *all* marriage be "illegal"

Comment: Does the privatization concept keep government benefits (lower taxes, etc...) in place and only "outsource" the contract portion or does it do away with them alltogether?

Comment: How? It's not like marriage privatization doesn't require registration. @Caleth

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but the state could still put people in jail for incest regardless of any private arrangements people have. It seems orthogonal to me. If the question is: can we have 'private marriage' with anything goes, except brothers and sisters marrying, i guess so if the law were drafted that way. But it would become impossible for the state to oversee inheritance or child custody, which is the bigger problem.

Comment: The state wouldn't need to oversee since the parties involved can make their own inheritance and child custody terms. @Ivana

Comment: I am very dubious about the claim that 'many people see it as a possible compromise between both sides'; it's difficult to find any polling on the matter, especially since 'many people' consider the matter to have already been compellingly settled by the Supreme Court and federal recognition. It's worth noting that even the Wikipedia page on the topic (which I agree with some of the commentators is currently hopelessly skewed) has almost no references from within the last decade.

Comment: I'm not sure why "religious conversatives" would object to polygamy, they seem to be a main supporter of that idea.

Comment: Except some Mormon fundamentalists and Islamic conservatives, I haven't found any religious conservatives supporting polygamy. @Erik

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury sure, but I don't think there's anyone else promoting the problematic type of "more than two people in a marriage" types at all. (Unless you think the entire concept of more than 2 people in love is a problem, but seems to be a separate question)

Comment: Well, many Libertarians think that the state shouldn't regulate polygamy. @Erik

Comment: Neither do I :) Maybe I'm just not sure why it's included in the question, since it doesn't seem relevant to the answers. It seems unrelated to incestuous relationships.

Comment: I just included as a sidenote. It isn't relevant. My only problem with marriage privatization is legalizing incestous relationships. @Erik

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Incest can happen with or without marriage. And it does, sadly, so clearly the current marriage laws don't prevent it.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury 'wouldn't need to oversee' - where i live any contract people have is only valid in so far as it is compliant with the law and with what is considered reasonable.So any provisions that are not reasonable or not compliant will not hold. Since custody of a child or ownership of say real-estate is a legal construct, the state must oversee it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept of "marriage" has several overlapping meanings.

- **The state** recognizes (and possibly subsidizes) a long-term relationship between several persons, traditionally one man and one woman.

  - Tax and inheritance law.
  - Custody of children.
  - Implicit power of attorney.
  - Legalization of some sexual relationships which would otherwise be illegal. (That can be an issue if the [age of marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriageable_age) is lower than the general [age of consent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_consent) or if a married couple travels to places with a different age of consent.)
- **Religions** recognize a long-term relationship, usually one man and one woman.
- **Society** recognizes a long-term relationship, similar to religious recognition but more fuzzy.

The first bullet point is one where **the state** requires clear records. It would be awkward if a rich person dies and the question of marriages and divorces becomes a matter of "he said, she said."

*So to your question*, the state could easily ban certain sexual relationships **inside and outside marriage**, and require that **relationships are registered** for the other benefits. Of course that is easier against incest than against polygamy.

Comment: However both of those possibilities conflict with "keeping the government out of marriage"

Comment: @Caleth, the first option would get the state out of marriage for regulation of intercourse. To get it completely out of marriage would require the abolishment of all legal privileges for married couples.

Comment: I don't understand why people think marriage privatization precludes registration. It doesn't.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury, depends on the role of the registry. Do they simply stamp it "witnessed, date and place" or do they refuse to register inappropriate marriages? If it is the latter, the marriage is not *really* private.

Comment: @Caleth Suppose certain behavior is banned both inside and outside marriage. If enforcing disregards marital status as well, it's totally decoupled from marriage. Why do you think this would not "keep the government out of marriage?"

Answer (score 4):

One of the fidgety problems with Libertarian/anarchist privatization theories is the enforcement of contracts. It's easy to say that two people can enter into a contract with each other according to their wishes, but that presents some difficult problems...

- How is the contract enforced if one person decides to violate it?
- How do we ensure that both parties entered into the contract willingly, and without force?

The kind of solutions that Libertarians and anarchists offer for that — e.g., social reputation, such that someone who violates one contract will find other people unwilling to enter into new contracts — don't really apply to personal matters like this. If marriage is supposed to be a one-at-a-time deal, then someone who violates their marriage contract already has a willing partner who might enter into a second contract, and someone who forces another to marry them doesn't need to worry about others not wanting to create marriage contacts with them.

Traditionally the state has taken on the role of arbiter in marriage, creating a standardized system that prevents and punishes contract violation. By registering the marriage with the state, each person can guarantee enforcement of the contract across the entire territory of the state, and questions of 'force' (which often occur in incest and marriage to minors) can be precluded. The problem with state certification has always been that the state goes *beyond* its role as contract enforcer to enforce religious or secular moral codes. The idea of private contracts without state registration and regulation is unworkable, but the state role can be scaled back to mere certification of the contract as valid and consensual.

Comment: What about adultery? It was a crime in the past, but was decriminalized and privatized over the last couple of decades. You seem to argue that this couldn't possibly have worked.

Comment: @Sjoerd: As I understand it, adultery is not longer *criminal* — i.e., punishable by jail or fines — but is still considered grounds for divorce (an equivalent to a civil law 'breach of contract' that allows the dissolution of an agreement). if marriages were purely private contracts, with no government enforcement, what consequences could there be for adultery?

Comment: Given that "unreconcilable differences" is also a ground for divorce, all this "ground for divorce" seems outdated anyway - if one spouse doesn't want to continue, forcing them to continue seems to be very anti-libertarian. To answer your question about consequences: whatever is specified in the contract.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Well, that's just part of the ridiculousness that is Libertarianism. Basically, a Libertarian is going to have to (ultimately) do away with the concept of marriage, and make all relationships matters of indefinite term contracts, where every citizen needs to spell out in detail all the provisions of their relationship, but no one can actually *enforce* any of them. So one person violates the contract by having an affair, and the other person violates it by changing the locks on the door and depriving the first of all common property. Great system...

Comment: -1. You clearly are not a libertarian, so are in no position to faithfully represents a libertarian's position about such contracts. Instead you are postulating strawmen. Not worth my time, but clearly worth a down vote.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I'm trained as a political scientist, which means I have quite a bit better understanding of Libertarianism than most Libertarians do. Of course, I don't expect you to understand or agree, but you might want to open your eyes a bit.

Comment: The state also checks if the persons getting married are not already married. This intentionally  is not part of the 'private contract' way of thinking, so as to allow polygamy/andry/whatever. But then what does it mean for the first marriage if one or both partners enter into another union?